# How to full page a div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if there is any way to set one div container to full page (like a zoom, with no other elements of the page shown) and allow user to turn back to normal by doing a escape or click outside of the div element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use jQuery UI for this solution. It's really simple and straight forward.

[Here's the Fullscreen working Demo of this effect](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/zcxKU/embedded/result/)

[Here's the Fiddle broken down piece by piece](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/zcxKU/)

And of course, the code ->

The HTML ->

```
<div class="body">
  <a href="#" id="open-modal"> Open Modal </a>
  <div class="overlay"></div>  
  <div id="modal" title="the modal"> Modal </div>
</div>
```

The CSS ->

```
body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:50px;
}
.ui-widget-overlay{
  z-index:10;   
}
.ui-dialog{
  z-index:20;   
}
```

The jQuery ->

```
$('#modal').dialog({
  'autoOpen' : false,
  'modal' : true
});
$('#open-modal').click(function(){
  $('#modal').dialog('open');
  $('.overlay').addClass('ui-widget-overlay');    
});

$(document).on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function(){
  $(this).removeClass('ui-widget-overlay');
  $('#modal').dialog('close');    
});
```